# How to Override "ir.sequence" field in csv import in Odoo?

Tags: csv, import, odoo

I'm trying to import new customer data into Odoo using CSV import. There is one field `customer_id_no` which is auto generated when the record is created(using the "ir.sequence").

Now each customer record in the CSV has a unique `customer_id_no` but when I try to import it, the existing `customer_id_no` is overridden by the standard sequence.

How can I insert the data from CSV as it is in the Odoo?

Also I was unable to find an answer to import many2one fields. Any help on that would be greatful.

Comment: I've never came across of a field `customer_id_no`. Could it be, that this field is a custom field? The Import is using the create() of a model, and when this sequence usage isn't implemented well, you can't do nothing about, but changing this implementation. An example for a good implementation of using a sequence but allowing import of data is the model `sale.order`.

Comment: The field `customer_id_no` is a custom field in a custom module and the code for sequence is also written in custom module.

Comment: @CZoellner I even tried disabling the sequence from Settings -> Technical -> sequences & Identifiers and then I imported the data, but unfortunately it did not work.

Comment: I think you need to change the implementation of the used custom module. Seems that this module is setting a sequence whether you create directly with a customer_id_no (import) or not (usual case).

Answer (score 1):

@CZoellner is right. You have to change your method. It would be something like this :

```
@api.model
def create(self, vals):
    vals['customer_id_no'] = mechanics_to_generate_sequence()
    return super(ClassName, self).create(vals)
```

It needs to address the case where customer_id_no is provided. Like this

```
@api.model
def create(self, vals):
    if not vals.get('customer_id_no'):
        vals['customer_id_no'] = mechanics_to_generate_sequence()
    return super(ClassName, self).create(vals)
```

Note that afterward you would need to make the sequence next iteration to the value next to the highest in `customer_id_no`.